# Is there a command in HTML5/CSS3 to resize the browser window to fit a webpage?

Tags: css, html, resize

Please note: I don't want to resize my own page, just the browser window, as soon as the user accesses my site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with HTML or CSS. You can do it with JavaScript *if* the user hasn't configured their browser to prevent this. (I have set this in my browser as it is *very* annoying).

A better solution is to use responsive design. Your website adjusts to their browser width instead of the other way around.

Comment: Can you give me tips to make a responsive design?

Comment: [There's lots of great tips and tutorials out there.](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=responsive+design)

Answer (score 2):

Wrong approach, your site should adapt to the person's screen, not vice-versa. My LCD's screen resolution is 1920x1200 and it irritates me that so many sites still to this day waste most of the screen. In fact SO uses exactly half of the width of my screen, only 960 pixels out of 1920 in width.

You should use percentages for your main layouts and stick to using margins. If you use padding use it very sparingly and only in very specific situations. My site in my profile is a perfect example of dynamic/liquid/adaptive layout as it's designed to work irregardless of whether you're on a tiny phone or a huge multi-monitor HD screen setup.

Comment: The problem with your site is that parts of it vanish the smaller resized in a browser...

Comment: And your users will vanish as well if you force their browser window to resize when they land on your site. That's a big No-No when creating websites. Adapt to your users, don't force them to adapt to you.

Comment: That is the point, the smaller the screen the more objective one has to be with what is displayed. That's called CSS3 Media Queries though you should concentrate on CSS1 width and margins first.

Comment: I know that I should be using responsive formats, but this is for an experiment that will later integrate a story line. The code I presented and my own website are currently only for test purposes.

Comment: If *I'm* telling you it's a bad idea then it really is a bad idea.